# Can a dog go into heat again after just 2 months?

Tags: dogs, health

We've got a small dog that is now ca. 8 months old an we had her for 2.5 months. Shortly after we got her she went into her first heat. We assume that when we got her she was already in the pre-heat stage because her behavior was very submissive. After her heat she acted much more confident, but at that time we assumed she just got used to us and her new home.

Now, after only 2 months, we notice her behavior changed back to being extremely submissive, her vulva is swollen and she has ever-so-slightly pink discharge. There was no incident that could have triggered her submissiveness.

I read that small dogs go into heat more often than big ones, but is it even possible for her to go into heat only 2 months after her first heat? We wanted to get her neutered, but if she goes into heat now we have to reschedule.

Comment: I can only talk about my experience with the bernese mountain dog of my parents in law. She was much more in heat than common and were diagnosed with some kind of cancer in the "reproduction area" (I am sorry I do not know more). When in heat she smelled sometimes badly and there was fluid out of the "repr. area", which was caused by the disease. I assume your dog is in close view of the vet. I wish you it is a less problematic cause for her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're just back from the vet and although he didn't outright say it's *impossible*, he confirmed that it's neither normal nor healthy for a dog to go into heat after such a short time. An ultrasound couldn't find a definite cause for the blood, though.

Update: The bleeding disappeared after a few days of antibiotics, so it was an inflammation. Though we don't know whether her uterus or bladder was infected. Her super submissive behavior was an additional symptom and sign that she didn't feel well.